# How to save memory in a Python calculator

Tags: python

I am running into a bit of an issue with a calculator properly saving memory and being able to recall it later for additional calculations. I have set this up a GUI for this and it is functioning properly, but the memory is not saving. I am either receiving the 'Error' or 'Memory is empty' statements and I am not sure why.

I will include a snippet of the code but can provide more if necessary. Any help here would really be appreciated.

Additional info:

```
memory = 0 
expression = ''

def memorySave():
    global memory, expression
    try:
        expression += str(memory)
    except:
        equation.set("Error")

def memoryRecall():
    global expression, memory
    if memory:
        expression += str(memory)
        equation.set(expression)
    else:
        equation.set("Memory is empty")
    
def memoryClear():
    global expression, memory
    memory = 0
    equation.set(str(memory))
```

Comment: You are declaring `memory` in every function, essentially resetting it.

Comment: The only time you assign a value to the `memory` variable is in `memoryClear`. Do you also mean to set its value in `memorySave`?

Answer (score 0):

Where is `equation` declared ? What is `set()` a method of ? I would avoid global variables entirely and maybe set up a Calculator class in which `memory`, `expression`, and `equation` are attributes:

```
class Calculator:

    def __init__(self):
        self.memory = 0
        self.expression = ''
        self.equation = ''

    def memoryAdd(self):
        expr = input("Enter number:")
        self.memory += int(expr)

    def memorySave(self):
        try:
            self.expression += str(self.memory)
        except:
            raise ValueError("Error")

    def memoryRecall(self):
        if self.memory:
            self.equation = self.expression
        else:
            raise ValueError("Memory is empty")

    def memoryClear(self):
        self.memory = 0
        self.expression = ''
        self.equation = ''


test = Calculator()
test.memoryAdd()
print(test.memory, type(test.memory))
test.memorySave()
print(test.expression, type(test.expression))
test.memoryRecall()
print(test.equation, type(test.equation))
test.memoryClear()
print(test.memory, type(test.memory))
```

running it would give you:

```
Enter number:7
7 <class 'int'>
7 <class 'str'>
7 <class 'str'>
0 <class 'int'>
```

obviously, you'd need to tailor it according to the library you're working with whereas here I just assume equation is also a string. And, here, I put an input statement in `memoryAdd()` but this would be where you handle the button click from your calculator GUI.